# customize evil ex prompt

Tags: evil, minibuffer, prompt

I'm wondering if there's any way, even if via advice or re-definition, to customize the evil ex prompt. Sometimes I invoke it instead of `M-:` to evaluate an expression, so I was thinking of showing a propertized string there to make it really stand out.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a customizable for that (see the `read-from-minibuffer` call in `evil-ex`).  Feel free to open a PR if it bothers you greatly that the colon doesn't stand out, otherwise redefining the command (after it has been loaded) will suffice.